# How to disable dates after current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have two views with two js files,and one datepicker in each view, i write this code to disable dates after current date in the two datepickers, but this work in the first one and don't work in the second.

this work

```
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setTime(yesterday.valueOf() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$("#date_naissance_patient").datepicker('option','maxDate',yesterday );
```

this don"t work :

```
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setTime(yesterday.valueOf() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$("#date_naissance").datepicker('option','maxDate',yesterday );
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to define "yesterday". try this one:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#date_naissance" ).datepicker();
       $( "#date_naissance" ).datepicker("option","maxDate","-1d"); 
  });
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4K6Q/6/) for you.

Comment: @kernelpromotion - Are you sure that #date_naissance is valid? This answer is the correct way to limit the maxDate. What is not working for you?

Comment: this is the problem, the solution work with the first datepicker mais don't work with the second one, this make me crazy, and #date_naissance is valide i test it with alert(jQuery("#date_naissance").val());

Comment: maybe you should check your codeblocks for missing characters. can you link us a jsfiddle for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This will 'disable' dates from yesterday onwards.

```
$("#date_naissance").datepicker({maxDate: '-2'});
```

The '-2' is the number of dates 'from which to disable'.

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw6PD/1/)